# sql how can I do get the first and last date when in two columns different rows (islands problem)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I think this problem is called islands and I'm looking on the net but not getting it.
I have a table where I need to get the start date and end date (different columns) in a range.

[image]

The table has 100,000 rows and I want to group it down so result will be

[image]

I have created a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f4800/1

From the internet I think I need to create rows so have this now:

[image]

But I'm stuck thinking over what my next step will be.

Comment: Why you have a same date finish `11/04/2015` for `LIVE` ?

Comment: It's a different CodeID, CODE1 and CODE2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()` & use the difference of sequences :

```
select [CodeID], min([DATE_START]) as DATE_START, 
       max(DATE_FINISH) as DATE_FINISH, state
from (select [CodeID],[DATE_START],[DATE_FINISH],[STATE],
             row_number() over(partition by [CodeID] order by [DATE_START]) as seq1,
             row_number() over(partition by [CodeID],[STATE] order by [DATE_START]) as seq2
      from Row_State 
      --where codeid = 'code1'
     ) t
group by [CodeID], state, (seq1-seq2)
order by CodeID, DATE_START;
```

Here is [db](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f4800/22) fiddle.

Comment: That's really neat how the (seq1-seq2) creates the grouping.

Comment: I need to run it across many different where codeid = 'code1'

Comment: @RogerClerkwell. . . Updated.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh I understand it now

Comment: What does seq1 - seq2 do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the final result will be tiled in time with no gaps, then you can also use `lag()` and `lead()` like this:

```
select code_id, state, date_start,
       lead(date_start) over (partition by code_id order by date_start) - interval '1 day' as day_end
from (select rs.*,
             lag(state) over (partition by code_id order by date_start) as prev_state
      from row_state rs
     ) rs
where prev_state is null or prev_state <> state;
```

The only issue with this version is that it does not correctly calculate the final date.  But for that:

```
select code_id, state, date_start,
       coalesce(dateadd(day, -1, lead(date_start) over (partition by code_id order by date_start)),
                max_date_end
               ) as day_end
from (select rs.*,
             lag(state) over (partition by code_id order by date_start) as prev_state,
             max(date_end) over (partition by code_id) as max_date_end
      from row_state rs
     ) rs
where prev_state is null or prev_state <> state;
```

This could be faster than an approach that uses aggregation.

Comment: Guess I would replace Internal with DateDiff, I'll play around with it as above solution also looks good, thanks

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . I'm pretty sure this was originally tagged Postgres.  In any case, removing that is a simple change.

Comment: Just so I know as writing up my notes for future reference, am I right in sql this is called 'Islands problem' or would you call it something else? thanks

Comment: @RogerClerkwell . . . It is called "gaps-and-islands".  But you want to be careful, because there are actually many different ways to approach such problems.  Some people think there is only one way.